# jquery, optimization, refreshing several divs on same page

Tags: jquery, optimization, refresh

I have a page where a user can remove a weblink, when the user clicks on the link to remove the weblink, the following code is executed:

```
// DELETE WEBLINK -->
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#delete_weblink').live('click', function(e){
     $('#leftside div#weblinks_wrapper').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #weblinks_wrapper') 
     $('#items_header_my_weblinks #weblink_count').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #weblink_count' )      
     $('#bottom_middle').load( $(this).attr('href') + ' #bottom_middle' )
     e.preventDefault(); 
}); 
});
```

So with this code, I'm refreshing 3 containers on the same page when the user removes a weblink, this causes the browser to request the page 3 different times.  So my question is.. is there a better approach? So that the browser only requests the page once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`id`s are absolute, so there is no need to be verbose. You can use a `GET` request, as they all point to one URL:

```
$('#delete_weblink').live('click', function(event) {
   $.get($(this).attr('href'), function(data) {
     $data = $(data);

     $.each(['#weblinks_wrapper', '#weblink_count', '#bottom_middle'], function() {
       $(this).html($data.find(this).html());
     });
   });

   event.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: You are misusing return false.

Comment: I was about to click "Post Your Answer" when the other answers posted dialog came up and you had the same code :P **EDIT** @Cokegod, how so?

Comment: @Cokegod: `return false;` is the same as `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`.

Comment: Correct, but you don't know if bubbling is important here. Generally, it is better not to use return false. http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/

Comment: I doubt the OP has any more events tied to that element, but I'll change my answer just in case.

Comment: Getting an error:

`Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMText.compareDocumentPosition]
[Break On This Error] (b[1]=(b[1]||"").toLowerCase(),b[3]=b[...h){var a=this.pushStack(this,"after" `

Comment: What browser are you testing this on? Can you post a live demo of that site? The error has a source, and it is in my code.

Comment: using both firefox and chrome.  your code is causing an error with the jquery library itself.  I don't know. does it work for you?

Comment: I don't have any way to test the code, so I sadly can't say. The code is valid and *should* work, but without a live site that I can debug I cannot say what's wrong using that error message alone...